# Event Handling form C# to vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I inherited this code from a C# sdk and I'm trying to convert it to vb.net. As I'm a bit new to vb.net, with the aid of some online converters I managed to convert it as below:

Original Code:

```
private void ScanThreadPorc()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            uint evt = Win32.WaitForMultipleObjects(2, hEvent, false, Win32.INFINITE);
            switch (evt)
            {
                case 0://return thread
                    return;
                case 1://disable network 
                    uint bytesRead;
                    uint flags;

                    byte[] buf = new byte[256];

                    if (Win32.ReadMsgQueue(hEvent[1], buf, 256, out bytesRead, Win32.INFINITE, out flags))
                    {
                         EventHandler<DecodeEventArgs> temp = DecodeEvent;
                         if (temp != null)
                         {
                             temp(this, new DecodeEventArgs(Encoding.Default.GetString(buf, 2, (int)bytesRead), buf[1]));
                         }
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Converted Code

```
Private Sub ScanThreadPorc()
        While (True)
            Dim evt As UInteger = Win32.WaitForMultipleObjects(2, hEvent, False, Win32.INFINITE)
            Select Case evt
                Case 0 '://return thread
                    Return
                Case 1 '://disable network 
                    Dim bytesRead As UInteger
                    Dim flags As UInteger
                    Dim buf As Byte() = New Byte(255) {}
                    If Win32.ReadMsgQueue(hEvent(1), buf, 256, bytesRead, Win32.INFINITE, flags) Then
                        Dim temp As EventHandler(Of DecodeEventArgs) = DecodeEvent
                        RaiseEvent temp(Me, New DecodeEventArgs(Encoding.[Default].GetString(buf, 2, CInt(bytesRead)), buf(1)))
                    End If
            End Select
        End While
    End Sub
```

I have 2 errors on DecodeEvent that says

> Public Event DecodeDevent (sender as object, e as DecodeEventArgs) is an event and cannot be called directly. Use a raise statement to raise an event.

And the second error on temp that says

> temp is not an event of myapplication.mynamespace.myclass.

I have read about 10 related topics on this and other forums but I'm unable to adapt the answers to my code.

Please help. Thanks

Comment: It's kind of hard to know what the problem is without knowing how `DecodeEvent` is implemented. In any case, try removing the `RaiseEvent` statement and call the `temp` method directly. Another thing to try would be to try to raise the event using this code: `RaiseEvent DecodeEvent(Me, New DecodeEventArgs(Encoding.[Default].GetString(buf, 2, CInt(bytesRead)), buf(1)))`

Comment: Remove line `Dim temp As EventHandler(Of DecodeEventArgs) = DecodeEvent` and change event raising to `RaiseEvent DecodeEvent(Me, New DecodeEventArgs(Encoding.[Default].GetString(buf, 2, CInt(bytesRead)), buf(1)))`

Comment: Thanks a bunch @xfx and Alex B. All errors cleared. Thank you